# Clear Intent in ionic android

Tags: android, angular, android-intent, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Ionic [WebIntent](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-intent/) for getting shared intent values from websites and opening modal popup on app thereafter.

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  this.clearIntent();
  console.log('APP CLOSED');
});
```

Just before closing the application , I want to clear shared intent or possibly send an empty intent so that the previous shared values are not coming up.

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka , Inside app component I am getting shared intent values from chrome which I use to open modal PopUps. Now If I keep pressing back button , the app closes. Now again If I open the app , it shows up the previous modal PopUp with the previous shared intent.
I want to clear the shared intent value on app closing or some empty intent which doesn't let the modal popUp come up